# How to wrap an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hyperlink

I don't understand very well this code:

```
var img = $('<img/>', {class: "photo", src: photo.url_n, width: wt, height: ht}).css("margin", border + "px");
```

It seems to create an image tag: `<img src="" class="photo" ... />`. I just want to wrap it with a link: `<a href="#aaaa"></a>`

But I am trying this and it doesn't work:

```
$(img).wrap('<a></a>');
```

I have also tried just:

```
img.wrap('<a></a>');
```

Finally the code add the `img` to another element like this:

```
d_row.append(img);
```

Comment: did you tried: `$(img).wrap('<a />');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** since `img` is created as a jQuery object, you don't need to write `$(img)` and wrap it in a jQuery object again. Just `img` will suffice.

**Second:** if `img` hasn't been `append`ed to the document yet, then you can't modify it in-place with `wrap()`.

**Third:** [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is designed to return the contents of the wrapped object, not the wrapper itself. You need to call `parent()` to get that.

Try:

```
img = img.wrap('<a>').parent();
```

(you don't need the closing `</a>`, jQuery will generate it automatically)

http://jsfiddle.net/TMeP6/

**However:** since `img` is no longer an image, the variable name `img` is inaccurate and potentially confusing. I would create a new variable name (`a_img` or something) and store it in that instead:

```
a_img = img.wrap('<a>').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d_row.append('<a>'+img+'</a>');
```

Or do you need more control?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it after you have append it to the DOM and it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Es6S/